# Bootstrap input field autofocus doesn't let you type

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap, and I have an input field with a drop down where the user can either click on the button or the input field to get the drop down. Now here lies the issue when the user clicks on the input field they can't type anymore :/

I've tried autofocus and no luck, can any one take a look.

Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row" style="padding:100px 0 0">
<div class="col-md-5">
<div class="input-group" style="padding: 0 0 10px 0;">
<div class="input-group-btn">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Action 
<span class="caret"></span>    </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /btn-group -->
    <input type="text" class="form-control inputBut" aria-label="...">
  </div>

  <!-- /input-group -->   
      <p class="well well-sm">When a user clicks on the input field to type the focus doesn't stay and the user can't type :/.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
$(function () {
$('.form-control').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('inputBut')) {
setTimeout(function() {$('.input-group-btn     button').click();},10);
        } else {
            $(this).parent().find('.input-group-addon').click();
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0bujq8ah/1/)

Comment: Please elaborate on this "the user can either click on the button or the input field to get the drop down". Do you want if user click on textbox, then the dropdown expand but the cursor still on textbox and you still can type or what ?

Comment: You are correct, when the user clicks on the textbox then the dropdown expands but the cursor still on textbox and you still can type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this logic on this line

`$('.input-group-btn button').click();`

I guessing that you want to trigger a click and expand the dropdown whenever you click on the textbox, actually you could simply

`$('.input-group-btn').addClass("open");`

here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/machun/gzbmtkk3/3/) for you, but i'm still dont get what the else condition trying to achieve on this line

```
$(this).parent().find('.input-group-addon').click();
```

you don't even have that class on your html

Comment: All I can say is "WoW" This is so much efficient than what I had before, thank you @machun